# need a restart server script in 1 hour if not stopped

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I am working on a remote servers network setup.
What I need is a script that will rename the "/etc/network/interfaces" file and then restart the computer. The renaming I got but what I don't get is how i can terminate this script in case I don't need it.
See if everything works out fine I like to issue a stop command that will terminate this script, so that the server doesn't restart.

So here is what I got so far. the issues are:

1. It doesn't return the prompt
2. The stop command doesn't work. It doesn't get the pid file for some reason. It returns "rm: missing operand" although the echo  tells me that the pid file is called "start.pid" and it is present in the /tmp folder

Any ideas?

```
#! /bin/sh

PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin

. /lib/lsb/init-functions


case "$1" in
  start)  
        ;;
    export PIDFILE=/var/run/${1}.pid
    ps -fe | grep ${1} | head -n1 | cut -d" " -f 6 > ${PIDFILE}

        sleep 30 #3600 

        log_action_msg "WARNING: Will in 60 sec rename /etc/network/interfaces and then restart"
        sleep 30# 60

        SUFFIX=$(date +%s)
        #cp /etc/network/interfaces /etc/network/interfaces.$SUFFIX
        cp /tmp/interfaces /etc/network/interfaces.$SUFFIX
        sleep 1
        #cp /etc/network/interfaces.org /tmp/interfaces
        cp /tmp/interfaces.org /tmp/interfaces
        sleep 1
        #reboot -d -f -i
        ;;
  stop)
    if [ -f ${PIDFILE} ]; then
        rm ${PIDFILE}
    fi

    exit 0

        ;;
  *)
        echo "Usage: $0 start|stop" >&2
        exit 3
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: Final script can be found here: http://wiki.robotamer.com/linux/network_safety_restart.sh

Answer (score 1):

Usually this is done using a 'pid-file' - a predetermined file that holds the process identifier of the currently running process. That way if it is called and told to stop, it looks up the pid-file and uses the `kill` command to send a signal to the currently running process.

There is another benefit of this as well - if you check for the existence of a pid-file (and the existence of that process) when the script is told to start, you can prevent accidentally starting the script twice, which would make stopping both instances problematic.

Answer (score 1):

The `stop` action can create a file `do.not.restart.server` in an appropriate location.

The `start` action can be modified to check whether the `do.not.restart.server` file exists, and avoid restarting the server if it is. It can/should probably remove the file for future restarts - or maybe it should remove it before it goes to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here is a working script, it does what I need. The only improvement I could still wish for is how to return the prompt from the sleep command. 
The functionality is there so I am posting it in case others needed as well.

Thanks Dan and Jonathan Leffler for your help and ideas.

```
#! /bin/sh

PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

export PIDFILESTART=/tmp/network-safty-restart-start.pid
export PIDFILESTOP=/tmp/network-safty-restart-stop.pid
#export FILE=/etc/network/interfaces
export FILE=/tmp/interfaces

case "$1" in
  start)  
    if [ -f ${PIDFILESTART} ]; then
            rm ${PIDFILESTART}
    fi
    if [ -f ${PIDFILESTOP} ]; then
            rm ${PIDFILESTOP}
    fi  
    ps -fe | grep ${1} | head -n1 | cut -d" " -f 6 > ${PIDFILESTART}

        sleep 3600 

        log_action_msg "WARNING: Will in 60 sec rename ${FILE} and then restart"
        sleep 60

    if ! [ -f ${PIDFILESTOP} ]; then
        log_action_msg "Restarting NOW"
            SUFFIX=$(date +%s)
            cp ${FILE} ${FILE}.${SUFFIX}
            sleep 1
            cp ${FILE}.org ${FILE}
            sleep 1
            reboot -d -f -i
    else
        rm ${PIDFILESTOP}
        log_action_msg "NOT Restaring as you wish"
        fi
        ;;
  stop)
    if [ -f ${PIDFILESTART} ]; then
            rm ${PIDFILESTART}
        ps -fe | grep ${1} | head -n1 | cut -d" " -f 6 > ${PIDFILESTOP}
        log_action_msg "Terminating restart script"

    fi
    log_action_msg "Terminated restart script"

    exit 0
        ;;
  *)
        echo "Usage: $0 start|stop" >&2
        exit 3
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: Don't need all that "ps -fe | grep ${1} | head -n1 | cut -d" " -f 6 > ${PIDFILESTOP}" do I now. Maybe someone can fix that, I am good now.